# Title a PDF page [FPDF]

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm generating some PDF on my site (with FPDF library) and I can't manage to change the title displayed in the browser (not the one when downloading, but the one corresponding to the HTML)

```
<title></title>
```

Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can set/change the title by:

```
$pdf->SetTitle('Title');
```

Reference: http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/settitle.htm

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't want to change the title of the document when you want to download it, but the one displayed in the browser tab

Comment: This is the official way. The tab name is response of the browser itself. You can workaround this by using `iframe` or setting filename header.

Comment: I'm trying to use : header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
But it doesn't work neither... What am I doing wrong ?